# Y-DNA haplogroup R1a1ab2 Z93 Z94 in England?

Tags: england, dna, y-dna, haplogroup, norfolk

I have just had my DNA results returned and my Y-DNA has come back as this. [image]

I am from East Anglia and my family has been documented in this region for the last thousand years, I am rather confused as to how I have got this result. Are there many others in England with this? Is it possible to have been carried here with the Vikings when East Anglia was under Danelaw? Are there any pockets of this within Scandinavia?

---

Update: Thank you for your reply sadly I have only just seen it. the only information I have is this chart as you say it does seem rather bizarre

[image]

Comment: Andrew can you clarify which site you got this off of and which specific test you did specifically. Such as was this a Y STR test or a YSNP test or an Autosomal DNA test. As well can you narrow your question down a little bit further as it is pretty broad and their are multiple questions in there with no one specific answer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply CRSouser, The test was taken with Living DNA I have tried to find what kind kind of test this was but sadly no luck. My question really is according to what I understand from these results is, my paternal line comes from the Z94 branch of R1A-Z93 which is South Asian. The results tell me there is 0% in the UK, but I am sure there must be odd exceptions, I was just trying to find a plausible explanation for this result.

Comment: of which subtype exactly? Z2125? paragroup Z93? M780?

Comment: The Farrar line in England is Z94, three of us have tested with Big Y which covers half the Y and is the most accurate way of doing it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The service you used, Living DNA, seems to try on its web site to avoid telling much about what kind of testing it is doing, especially avoiding standard terms.  Digging though its help system, it seems that is using SNP testing of autosomes and of sex chromosomes and mitochondria via an Illumina Orion testing chip.  The results include paternal and maternal haplogroups, which it calls "fatherline" and "motherline", and autosomal-based ethnicity, which it calls a "family ancestry test".

The map you provided I presume you got from their site and apparently shows frequency of either the R-Z93 paternal haplogroup or its R-Z94 subgroup.  Please note that it implies that your paternal haplogroup (or "fatherline") is known to occur in England and Scotland, but not in Wales or Ireland.  This is shown by the (light) shading of the first two but not the second two, and by the listing in the key of the first two only.  The key shows 0% for England and Scotland, but this can be taken to mean that it occurs in less than 1% (or perhaps 0.5%) of the males in England, but has been detected at some low percentage.

That you have the small piece of DNA called R-Z94 should not be thought particularly strange, just not typical.  (Some haplogroups occur at higher frequencies in England, and some at lower frequencies.)  How you happen to have this "fatherline" can't be determined.  You have perhaps 1600 nth-great grandfathers who carried it to you over the last 4000 or so years since R-Z94 split off from R-Z93.  Those men lived in various unknown places and some migrated between different areas, eventually landing in East Anglia.

Comment: Thank you so much Robert brilliant answer! very kind of you to go to so much trouble for me,

Comment: Also I am not sure about quality of SNP testing of Y chr with the help of Illumina chips. The most famous project using this kind of chips is NatGeno Geno2.0. It has a LOT of problems. Beginning from misread SNPs and homology of SNPs between different clades. It is serious task to find the place of tested person on Y tree. Taking in account that there are different versions of Y tree and they all are updated with time. Brh. So the best choice (but rather expensive!!!) to investigate somebody's direct paternal line is to order NGS test like BigY or FGS Y-Elite.

Comment: So if we don't know HOW AncestryDNA detected @Andrew Kett belongs to R-Z94, we can say nothing for sure. I hope that AncestryDNA guys are smart and don't use SWAG technology, but number of SNPs from their custom chip typical to one particular clade/subclade to make claims that somebody belongs it.

Comment: @GeorgeGaál, Andrew used "Living DNA" for testing, not AncestryDNA.

Comment: Ah, sorry, their names look the same :-) Everybody tries to make it's own DNA company, so mess takes place. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

My Y-haplogroup is R1a-Z93. The map comes from living DNA. It states 0% for England and Scotland. Given that living DNA is a British company, they are always going to include England in their maps as a reference point. R1a-Z93 is a haplogroup that is common amongst South Asians, Central Asians, and Ashkenazi Jews (who are descended from Khazars).

A friend of mine has the mtDNA of N1b1a which also comes up as 0% for the United Kingdom, yet it is shown on the map (purely as a reference point).

Comment: Igor Rozhanskii, and Anatole A Klyosin (The Academy of DNA Geneology, Newton USA) in their article, Haplogroup R1a, Its subclades and Branches in Europe during the Last 9000 Years, state that the only negative mutation of Z93 is in the United Kingdom. Eastern Europeans, including Ashkenazi Jews, have a positive mutation. They also point out that English and Scots people who have this haplogroup, are likely to be descended from Anglo-Indians. This makes sense. Others may have had an Ashkenazi Jewish male ancestor.

Comment: This haplogroup was not carried into England by Scandinavians. The Teutonic branch of R1a is L664. Your ancestry is either Anglo-Indian or Ashkenazi.

Answer (score -1):

Is your mutation YP1451 positive? Apparently it is the only -Z93 beyond Asia.. I happen to be on positive on that Mutation. which goes beyond my logic as our heritage if within another Mutation but still my raw data it being tested for Big-Y from FamilytreeDNA. I leaning towards it being a sham too.